# Django: Use same inmemoryuploadedfile to POST to multiple remote API's

Tags: django, rest, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I am trying to use the same inmemoryuploadedfile to multiple remote APIs.
The upload form consists of a single FileField. Once the user submits the file, I'm trying to use the same inmemoryuploadedfile to post the file to multiple remote APIs.

The first remote API call with the file gets successfully received at the remote API end. However, the second remote API call seems to fail as the remote API cannot read the file properly.
To debug, I set the two remote APIs with same exact code but deployed on different VMs. Still getting the same error.

It seems like only the first API call receives the file correctly and the second call always fails.

```
def form_valid(self, form):
   exp = form.save(commit=False)
   result1 = api_endpoint1(exp.image) # Passes 
   result2 = api_endpoint2(exp.image) # Fails- Doesnt receive file correctly
   if result1.json() == result2.json():
      print('All is Good!')
```

If I swap result1 and result2 line, then result2 passes and result1 fails.

Even if I do call same API, the second one fails:

```
    result1 = api_endpoint1(exp.image) # Passes 
    result2 = api_endpoint1(exp.image) # Fails- Doesnt receive file correctly
```

I tried reseeking the file with exp.image.seek(0), but it doesn't work.

I could save the file and then send the files to 2 APIs, which would work. But, would add additional overhead.

Is there any way, I could reuse the inmemoryuploadedfile multiple times to send the same file to multiple remote APIs.

Answer (score 0):

I was doing:

```
result1 = api_endpoint1(exp.image)
result2 = api_endpoint1(exp.image.seek(0))
```

Instead of the filehandle something else was being passed.

Only changes required was:

```
result1 = api_endpoint1(exp.image)
exp.image.seek(0)
result2 = api_endpoint1(exp.image)
```

Seek the file and then pass it to your functions.